# difference bwtween redis force failover and automatic failover caused by a master down

Tags: cluster, redis, failover

I want to use [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) `NewFailoverClinet` as a client to set data into my database(redis-3.2.6) in a loop.

Result shows using command `sentinel failover <MasterName>` to trigger failover could cause data lost, but log indicates all data is saved with `OK` response.

Using `kill -9 <masterPID>` to cause a automatic failover returns a correct log which matches perfectly with data saved in database

I want to know the mechanism of failover both triggered by command and master down